# setting of task size in Rstudio

Tags: r, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I am using Rstudio ,when I running my code,I'm faced with the following problem:

> taskSetManager:66 - Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (1045 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.

What does someone know about the problem and how do I fix it?

CODE:

```
library(readr)  
library(dplyr)
library(SparkR, lib.loc=c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
df <-read_delim("winequality-white.csv", delim = ";") %>%  
     dplyr::mutate(taste = as.factor(ifelse(quality < 6, "bad",  ifelse(quality > 6, "good", "average")))) %>%  
     dplyr::select(-quality)  
df <- dplyr::mutate(df, id = as.integer(rownames(df)))
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark")
sparkR.session(master="spark://master:7077")
ddf <- createDataFrame(df)
```

Comment: You can start by dropping `createDataFrame`. Load data directly with respective reade (`read.df(..., source = "csv", delim = ";", header = "true")`). But with such toy example I wouldn't worry and in this case you don't have any more control

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49089935/sparkr-stage-x-contains-a-task-of-very-large-size